# Why Srimad Bhagavatam Canto 9 Chapter 14 insults women too much?

Tags: scripture, puranas, bhagavata-purana, women

[SB 9.14.36](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/9/14/36)

> Urvaśī said: My dear King, you are a man, a hero. Don’t be impatient
>   and give up your life. Be sober and don’t allow the senses to overcome
>   you like foxes. Don’t let the foxes eat you. In other words, you
>   should not be controlled by your senses. Rather, you should know that
>   **the heart of a woman is like that of a fox. There is no use making
>   friendship with women.**

[SB 9.14.37](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/9/14/37)

> **Women as a class are merciless and cunning.** They cannot tolerate even a slight offense. For their own pleasure they can do anything irreligious, and therefore **they do not fear killing even a faithful husband or brother.**

[SB 9.14.38](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/9/14/38)

> **Women are very easily seduced by men.** Therefore, polluted women give up the friendship of a man who is their well-wisher and establish false friendship among fools. Indeed, they seek newer and newer friends, one after another.

Comment: If u are serious then devote sometime for reading a whole chapter of the text if not the whole text itself. Then u can come to a conclusion.

Answer (score 11):

The quotes you mentioned in your question are **not insulting women at all.** Although it looks like a insult , but we can't conclude that with just interpretation of 2-3 verses , without knowing the whole story and the background of it.

This chapter is about Chandra-Vamsha in which there is a story about Pururava and Urvashi. First of all let us see in what context and in which situation these sentences are said by Urvashi to Pururava.

The summery of which is as follows

> Urvashi the celestial nimph fells in love with Pururava and he
>   welcomes her and accepts her love proposal. Urvashi then hands him her
>   two lambs for protection and sets one condition that he should not
>   come in front of her naked. Meanwhile Indra knowing that Urvashi is
>   not present at his court sends two gandharvas to bring her back to
>   him.Those gandharvas stole the two lambs of Urvashi upon which
>   Pururava flights with them and brings them back (in naked condition in
>   hurry) and Urvashi leaves him as she sees him naked.

After that in lamenting, he began traveling about the earth like a madman.One day he spots Urvashi at kurukshetra (banks of river Saraswati)and says following to her.

> सुदेहोsयं पत त्यत्र देवि दुरं ह्यतस्त्वया ।
>  खादनत्येनं वृका
>   ग्रुध्रास्त्वतत्प्रसादस्य नास्पदम् ।।36।।
>
> sudeho ’yaṁ pataty atra devi dūraṁ hṛtas tvayā
>  khādanty enaṁ vṛkā
>   gṛdhrās tvat-prasādasya nāspadam
>
> O goddess, now that you have refused me, my beautiful body will fall
>   down here, and because it is unsuitable for your pleasure, it will be
>   eaten by foxes and vultures. [**SB 9.14.35**](http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/9/14/35)

And thus he decides to die in the sorrow of Urvashi.Then Urvashi says to him thus.

> मा मृथा: पुरुषोsसि त्वं मा स्म त्वाद्युवृका इमे।
>  क्कपि सख्यम न वै
>   स्त्रीणाम वृकाणाम ह्यदयं यथा।।36।।
>
> mā mṛthāḥ puruṣo ’si tvaṁ mā sma tvādyur vṛkā ime  kvāpi sakhyaṁ na
>   vai strīṇāṁ vṛkāṇāṁ hṛdayaṁ yathā
>
> Urvaśī said: My dear King, you are a man, a hero. Don’t be impatient
>   and give up your life. **Be sober and don’t allow the senses to overcome**
>   you like foxes. Don’t let the foxes eat you. In other words, you
>   should not be controlled by your senses. Rather, you should know that
>   the heart of a woman is like that of a fox. There is no use making
>   friendship with women.  [**SB 9.14.36**](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/9/14/36)

Now its quite clear that - Urvashi says this by knowing Pururava's wish to die in her love & in her grief. So she just says all this in order to give courage to pururava and inorder to drove away his thoughts of dying in her grief of her and **to tell him to control his senses.** **In other words intentionally to calm him down and to set his heart free of excessive love & lust etc.**

**There is no any intention of insulting  women in any way in that story nor it does so.Because Urvashi says this in different context as stated above and not in intention of  insulting  women**

Hinduism scriptures strongly respects women.And believes that   society only   flourishes in which women are given respect and treated with equality.

Comment: Fabulous answer!